# Finding new features in new QGIS version?

Tags: qgis

Where can I see the new features of the Qgis 2.16.1?
Is there a way to compare versions?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New features of QGIS main versions can be found here:

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelogs.html

You mention version 2.16.1, that is only a bugfix release to the major 2.16 version.

To compare versions, you can install both under Windows using the standalone installers from http://qgis.org/downloads/. They live happily next to each other, but plugins might not work with older versions anymore.

On Linux systems, you have to install older versions in virtual boxes with the OS they are compiled for.

Comment: thanks. The link https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelogs.html is useful for me.